# DRM for videos that are distributed using hard copy

Tags: drm

Is there any way to protect offline content using DRM ? i want to sell my videos offline to my clients. How i can make sure that content once copied to my clients Desktop , i.e window it will not further copy to any another machine?.

Answer (score -1):

The typical way to address this is not by preventing file copy, which is a hard problem. Current DRM systems all work according to the principle that the file itself can be freely copied, but it is encrypted, usually with some variation of AES-128. Then if the user has a decryption key (which is part of a "license" uniquely bound to the user's machine) he or she can play the content.

Common DRM-friendly file formats are Microsoft's [PIFF (Protected Interoperable File Format)](http://www.iis.net/learn/media/smooth-streaming/protected-interoperable-file-format), and [UltraViolet CFF (Common File Format)](http://www.uvdemystified.com/uvfaq.html#3.2), but there are others too.